# end1 can not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I just started using Eclipse to program C++ and I'm running into issues. I have MinGW installed. Right now I have a simple addition program as followed:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int sum;

    cout << "Enter first integer: ";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Enter second integer: ";
    cin >> number2;

    sum = number1 + number2;

    cout << sum << end1;

}
```

and I have an error `Symbol end1 could not be resolved` and `end1 was not declared in this scope`

I had this error before with `using namespace std;` and I had to go through some configurations to get the MinGW compiler to work with Eclipse. I don't understand why this error is still coming up. On a somewhat side note I tried removing `end1` and running the program and the console just said, "Info: Nothing to build for CTest" (which is the name of my Project folder name). Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The "can not be resolved issue has been fixed by changing `end1` to `endl` but the console is still saying "nothing to build"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo

change:

```
end1;
```

to

```
endl;
```

Comment: Ha, thank you guys. I'm using a book for reference and the l looks like a 1. Derp

Comment: I am still getting the  "Info: Nothing to build for CTest" message

Comment: Must be something relative to eclipse setup?

Comment: save your change or do project/clear on eclipse ....

Comment: ha, this just happened to me too, some fonts man... of course it's endl why would it be end1!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `end1` with `endl` and you're done.